# Startup Indicator 16.04

Tags: 16.04, indicator, startup-applications

360 Total Security has a feature that announces the end of startup activity on PC. Is it possible to have the same in Ubuntu as well ? 360 TS even shows the time taken to complete the startup process.

I ask this because it takes a while when 16.04 gets workable after login. I want to know whether the system is ready for use or not. Thanks.